# How to access elements of symmetric Eigen matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, accessor

My understanding of a symmetric matrix is that A(i,j) == A(j,i), but in Eigen only one of these is defined. What am I missing?

Here is an example below. I've also tried variations of that and don't seem to see an answer elsewhere. Am I supposed to manually ensure that the indices comply to some internal expectations?

```
MatrixXf m(4, 4);  // uninitialized 4x4
auto v = m.selfadjointView<Upper>(); // I don't need triangular matrix, but ok by me to store it only once
int i = 1;
int j = 3;
v(i, j) = 3.0f; // either v(i,j) or v(j,i) is undefined. How can I permit both?
std::cout << "\n"
          << v(j, i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing both halves by `(i,j)` is essentially not how `.selfadjointView<>()` is intended to work. Supporting that would require a `min`/`max` operation and for complex matrices even some kind of proxy-object, for each access which is quite expensive.

You should only access the upper half by the `()` operator and afterwards you can use the `SelfadjointView` object as part of other expressions, such as products, or use special methods like `rankUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation. That is what I was worried was the case. I was hoping Eigen had some matrix that handled the complexity of symmetry without pushing it to all the call sites